# Rails Form Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form like this in my html page

```
<%= form_for '/purchases', html: {class: "form form-horizontal validate-form", novalidate: "novalidate"} do |f| %>
```

But the form action is like this when i inspect the form

```
action = '/purchases/new'
```

I want the action to be just `/purchases`

and my controller method is like

@purchase = OrderItems.new

Answer (score 2):

If you have your routes configured properly, you just need:

```
<%= form_for @purchase, html: {class: "form form-horizontal validate-form", novalidate: "novalidate"} do |f| %>
```

of course, provided you set `@purchase` in your `new` action:

```
@purchase = Purchase.new
```

Comment: thing is i want to store all items into OrderItems Model..
So my controller is like @purchase = OrderItems.new

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting confused between [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) and [`form_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag)

--

**form_for** is for objects -

```
#app/controllers/purchases_controller.rb
Class PurchasesController < ApplicationController
   def new
       @purchase = Purchase.new
   end

   def create
       @purchase = Purchase.new(purchase_params)
       @purchase.save
   end

   private

   def purchase_params
       params.require(:purchase).permit(:purchase, :attributes)
   end
end
```

The important thing to note with `form_for` is how it will *build* your form out of the ActiveRecord object you define. This is vitally important, and is at the root of your error:

```
<%= form_for @purchase do |f| %>
```

This will build all the different attributes of the form (including the `action` attribute), from the ActiveRecord object itself. This means if you populate your `form_for` with anything other than an object, you're going to get into trouble (as exhibited by your error)

--

**form_tag** is for data -

```
<%= form_tag your_path do %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

This might be better suited to your circumstances, as it allows you to create a "standalone" form - one which gives you the ability to send non-model-centric data to your application

We use `form_tag` implementations for the likes of search facilities etc

---

**Solution**

As `Marek` pointed out, you need to populate your `form_for` with an ActiveRecord object. To do this, you need first ensure you have initialized the object in your controller's `new` action, before passing the value to the form:

```
#app/controllers/purchases_controller.rb
Class PurchasesController < ActiveRecord::Base
   def new
      @purchase = Purchase.new
   end

   ...
end

#app/views/purchases/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @purchase do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to elaborate on the answers presented here.  The way `form_for` works is it bases the form input names on the first argument passed to it.  You can pass string or symbol as the first argument, and it should work, just like your example.

```
= form_for :purchase do |f|
  = f.text_field :order
```

will result in a form that will submit to the current url and will contain 1 text field with the name `purchase[order]`.

Marek's answer is correct however it doesn't answer your question.  In cases where the object of the form, by convention, doesn't match the controller that will handle the request, you can pass a `url` option to `form_for`.

```
# controller
def new
  @purchase = OrderItem.new
end

# view
= form_for @purchase, url: '/purchases' do |f|
  = f.text_field :order
```

This will create a form with action set to `/purchases` but the name of the text field will be `order_item[order]`.

**FINAL NOTE**

`form_for` is not exclusively used for active record objects as stated in the [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for)